# number of leaves in a binary tree

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree, binary-search

I am a beginner to binary trees and have been working my way through the algorithms book. I have learnt about the various traversal  methods of BSTs (pre-order, post order etc).

Could someone please explain how one can traverse a BST to count the number of nodes that are leaves (no children) please?

Many thanks!

Comment: Use a recursive method: for a leaf return 1, for a non-leaf, return the sum of that method applied on its children.

Comment: Use any of the traversals you listed (preorder DFS, postorder DFS, BFS), and just test whether the node you're currently visiting has no children.  If so, increment the counter by 1.

Comment: Thanks!
Is there a basic implementation that you would recommend plz?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The different traversal methods would lead to different algorithms (although for a simple problem like this, all DFS variants are more or less the same).

I assume that you have a BST which consists of objects of type `Node`. A node has two fields `left` and `right` of type `Node`, which are the children of the node. If a child is not present, the value of that field is `null`. The whole tree is referenced by a reference to the root, called `root`. In java:

```
class Node {
    public Node left;
    public Node right;
}

Node root;
```

A DFS is easiest to implement by recursion: define a method

```
int numberOfLeafs(Node node)
```

which returns the number of leafs in the subtree rooted by `node`. Of course, `numberOfLeafs(root)` should yield the number of leafs of the whole tree.

As said, it is really artificial to distinguish pre-, in-, and post-order traversal here, but I'm gonna do it anyway:

**Pre-order DFS**: First deal with the current node, then with the children

```
int numberOfLeafs(Node node) {
    int result = 0;
    if (node.left == null && node.right == null)
        result += 1;
    if (node.left != null)
        result += numberOfLeafs(node.left)
    if (node.right != null)
        result += numberOfLeafs(node.right)
    return result;
}
```

**In-order DFS**: First deal with the left child, then with the current node, then with the right child

```
int numberOfLeafs(Node node) {
    int result = 0;
    if (node.left != null)
        result += numberOfLeafs(node.left)
    if (node.left == null && node.right == null)
        result += 1;
    if (node.right != null)
        result += numberOfLeafs(node.right)
    return result;
}
```

**Post-order DFS**: First deal with the children, then with the current node

```
int numberOfLeafs(Node node) {
    int result = 0;
    if (node.left != null)
        result += numberOfLeafs(node.left)
    if (node.right != null)
        result += numberOfLeafs(node.right)
    if (node.left == null && node.right == null)
        result += 1;
    return result;
}
```

---

For a **BFS**, you typically use a simple loop with a queue in which you add unvisited vertices. I now assume that I have a class `Queue` to which I can `add` nodes at the end and `take` nodes from the front:

```
Queue queue = new Queue();
queue.add(root);
int numberOfLeafs = 0;
while (!queue.empty) {
    // take an unhandled node from the queue
    Node node = queue.take();

    if (node.left == null && node.right == null)
        numberOfLeafs += 1;
    if (node.left != null)
        queue.add(node.left);
    if (node.right != null)
        queue.add(node.right);
}
```

Comment: Mate! I have read so many books and watched online tutorials. This is by far the best explanation of traversion BST's I have ever come across! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

Use a recursive method:

- For a leaf return 1.
- For a non-leaf, return the sum of that method applied to its children.

Example in PHP:

```php
class BST {
  public $left;  // The substree containing the smaller entries
  public $right; // The substree containing the larger entries
  public $data;  // The value that is stored in the node
}

function countLeafs(BST $b) {
  // Test whether children exist ...
  if ($b->left || $b->right) {
    // ... yes, the left or the right child exists. It's not a leaf.
    // Return the sum of calling countLeafs() on all children.
    return ($b->left  ? countLeafs($b->left)  : 0)
         + ($b->right ? countLeafs($b->right) : 0);
  } else {
    // ... no, it's a leaf
    return 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Nicely phrased ;-) +1

Comment: Thanks for that. You've answered the question. Could you kindly recommend a very basic implementation plz?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the implementation. I would be very grateful if you could kindly explain in english what your doing in the function countLeafs(BST $b) please!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
int countLeafNodes(BTNode node) { 
if (node == null)
        return 0;
    if (node.getLeftChild() == null && node.getRightChild() == null
            && node.getParent() != null)//this is a leaf, no left or right child
        return 1;
    else
        return countLeafNodes(node.getLeftChild())
                + countLeafNodes(node.getRightChild());
}
```

which recursively counts leaf nodes for left and right sub trees and returns the total count